# Modular equations and Euler's theorem

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Looking at group $U{81}$ find $0<x<81$ such that:

$$x^{19}=8 \:(mod\:81)$$

I know that $o(8)=18$, is it true to say:

$$(x^{19})^{18}=1 \:(mod\:81)$$

and from here to use Euler's theorem which yields:

$$x^{18}=1 \:(mod\: 81) \ ?$$

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I'm not sure it's useful. Instead, I'd start with $x^{19}\equiv8\bmod3$ and work my way up to moduli $3^2,3^3,3^4$. "Hensel's Lemma"

Comment: I'm not familiar with that lemma, will check it out but why it doesn't useful? I already know a number that his 18 power is equivalent to 1 (8)

Comment: @3xhaust Hensel's lemma is a lemma that allows one to lift congruences $\pmod{p}$ to $\pmod{p^2}$. This allows us to work with smaller congruences which might be easier to work. I think your approach is also fine but it's a bit difficult to find all the elements of order 18 directly.

Comment: Not just to $p^2$, @dar, but to $p^3$, $p^4$, ....

Comment: Use `$x\equiv y\pmod{n}$` for $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

$8$ isn't the only integer with order $18$, so solving $x^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{81}$ gives solutions which don't solve $x^{19}\equiv 8\pmod{81}$.

You can note that $(9-1)^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{81}$ to find the answer as $x=8$.

Comment: Cam you elaborate more please? I didn't understand how to use what you suggested

Comment: @3xhaust; as $8^{18}\equiv1\pmod{81}$ then $8^{19}\equiv8\pmod{81}$

Comment: But how can I find all the numbers that satisfy it?

Comment: @3xhaust; all numbers of the form $9k\pm1$.

Comment: What's the explanation for that? Especially for the +1?

Comment: @3xhaust; expand $(9k\pm1)^{18}$ with the binomial theorem - every coefficient except for the last is $0\pmod{81}$. (The font is hard to read - its plus/minus 1.)